# Sandbox Lua in Python and execute coroutine in the sandbox with debug hook

Tags: python, debugging, lua, sandbox, coroutine

I have a python programm and the user shall be able to do some scripting of his own in the interface. The language here shall be Lua. So far I have Lua sandboxed and can execute the user code all at once like this:

```
lua_sandbox = lua.eval('''
function()   
  local function run(untrusted_code)
    local untrusted_function, message = load(untrusted_code, nil, 't', _ENV)
    if not untrusted_function then return nil, message end
    return xpcall(untrusted_function, errorHandler)
  end

-------------------- Defining Python functions and objects in Lua -------------------

  local function PythonFunctionInLua(arg)
    return python.eval('PythonFunction(' .. arg ..')')
  end

  PythonObjectInLua = python.eval('PythonObject')

-- Pass them to the local Lua sandbox
  _ENV = { print = print,
           PythonFunction = PythonFunctionInLua,
           PythonObject = PythonObjectInLua,
           coroutine = coroutine }

  assert(run [[''' + code + ''' ]])
end
''')
```

So far, so good. Now I want to add the possibility to execute the code stepwise. Best Idea I had so far is using a debug hook for this, so I tried this:

```
... (from above until _ENV)
debug.sethook(scripterDebug, "l")
func = assert( run [[''' + code  + ''' ]] )
co = coroutine.create(func)
coroutine.resume(co)
```

Here comes the problem: I can't call `coroutine.yield` to pause the routine until the user clicks again to process the next line. Calling it from the outside, e.g. in the `scripterDebug` hook, as well as calling it from the inside (inserting it in the `code` part) result in `attempt to yield across C-Call boundary`t (I suppose beacuse I keep going in and out of the sandbox in the latter case).

I also tried creating the coroutine within the `run[[  ]]]`, an then yielding works, but I can't call `coroutine.resume(co)` on the outside because `co' is only known inside the sandbox. I have to call it from the outside because it is called when the user clicks to continue, and if I pass access to the UI etc. into the sandbox, the whole thing becomes useless.

Is there any way to execute this code stepwise in a sandbox nice and short?